# Does the Principal ever visit his granddaughter?

Tags: nichijou

In episode 26 of Nichijou, it's revealed that the Principal of the school...

> ...is Mr. Shinonome.

However, the relationship between him and

> his supposed granddaughter Hakase

is never elaborated on in the anime.

In the manga, is it ever stated if he at least *visits* her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question directly, there are no occurrences where the headmaster visits Hakase in any media, but *they have met once*.

In *Nichijou no Shousetsu* light novel, there's a chapter called "*Nichijou no Mukashibanashi*" (Everyday's Folklore) telling the story of *[Momotaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momotar%C5%8D)* with *Nichijou*'s characters. Hakase acted as Momotaro, while the headmaster's role was the dog. Here's the relevant script:

> さて、さるをお供にしたももたろうが、元気良く鬼が島に歩いて行くと、その途中で、今度は犬が現れました。
>   「……!」
>   「……!」
>   しかも、戦っています。
>   しかと、戦っています。
>   いぬ役の校長先生が、役をほっぽり出して、しかと戦っています。校長先生、出番ですよー!
>   [中略]
>   「な、なんでしかと戦っているのー!?」
>   このおじさんが校長先生だと知らないももたろうは、あわてるばかり。
>   たしかに、街中でいぬとしかが戦っていたら、誰だってびっくりします。

Translation:

> And so, the monkey that befriended Momotaro and the vigorous demon are walking toward the island. On the way, this time they see a dog.
>   "......!"
>   "......!"
>   Moreover, he is fighting.
>   He is fighting with a deer.
>   The headmaster whose role is the dog abandoned his role and is fighting with the deer. Headmaster, it's your turn now~!
>   [...]
>   "Wh-, why are you fighting with the deer!?"
>   Momotaro, who doesn't know that this old man (*ojisan*) is the headmaster, is only confused.
>   Certainly, everyone will be surprised seeing a dog and deer fighting each other in the middle of a road.

<sup>P.S. The headmaster's name was only mentioned in the anime.</sup>

---

Source: [Yahoo! Chiebukuro](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1195558141)